# Find a function $f_0 \in K$ for which $T(f_0) \leq T(f) \text{ for all } f \text{ in } K$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $E$ be a measurable set and $1 < p < \infty$. Let $T$ be a continuous linear functional on $L^p[a,b]$ and $K = \{ f \in L^p(E) \ | \ ||f||_p \leq 1\}$. Find a function $f_0 \in K$ for which
$T(f_0) \leq T(f) \text{ for all } f  \text{ in } K$.

I thought contradiction will be easy to use, but it did get me anywhere, any clues or solutions?

Continuity property of a bounded linear functional $T$: if $\{f_n\} \to f$ in $X$, then $\{T(f_n)\} \to T(f)$.

Comment: Is $E \subset [a,b]$?

Comment: Use that every bounded sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence, since $L^p$ is reflexive for $1<p<\infty$. Essentially, this is the direct method in the calculus of variations.

Comment: It does not mentions $E \subset [a,b]$

Comment: Just noticed the Theorem: Let E be a measurable set and $1 < p < \infty$. Suppose $C$ is a closed, bounded
convex subset of $L^p(E)$ and $T$ is a continuous convex functional on $C$. Then $T$ takes on a minimum value on $C$, that is, there is a function $f_o \in C$ such that $T(f_o) < T (f)$ for all $f \in C$. So according with this theorem we have to prove that $K$ is closed bounded convex, am i Right?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to leave this as a comment, but then I realized it was going to be kind of long, so this is just an observation, rather than an answer.

I'm not sure if it is true: if such a function $f_0$ existed, then this would imply that $|T(f_0)|\geq|T(f)|$ for all $f\in K$, but by definition
$$\|T\|\colon=\sup_{f\in K}|T(f)|=|T(f_0)|,$$
whence this means that the sup is actually a max, and I don't believe that to be true for an arbitrary functional on $L^P$? (Edit: by which I mean, it shouldn't be too hard to imagine a functional whose norm is *not* attained by some function?)